# Filter array of paths to keep only the shallowest paths

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of randomly sorted paths, I'd like to filter it so only the shallowest paths stay in the array. Any sub-paths should be removed.

My attempt below *does* filter some paths, but the end result is wrong and should be an array containing only these:

`[ '/video', '/audio', '/code', '/images', '/test/noparent' ]`

```
var paths = [
  '/code/client/images',
  '/code/client/templates/views',
  '/code/another/templates/views',
  '/code/client/svg',
  '/images',
  '/code/another',
  '/code/client',
  '/audio/asdasd',
  '/audio/asd',
  '/code/client/html',
  '/video',
  '/code/client/templates',
  '/audio/asd/asdasd',
  '/code/another/html',
  '/code/another/images',
  '/code/another/svg',
  '/code/another/templates',
  '/code',
  '/audio',
  '/test/noparent'
];

// prepare by sorting paths by number of slashes
paths.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.match(/\//g).length - b.match(/\//g).length;
});

// filter (this fails)
paths.filter(function (path) {
  var keep = true;
  paths.forEach(function (another) {
      if (another.indexOf(path) === 0 && another !== path) keep = false;
  });
  return keep;
});
```

Maybe there's a solution that doesn't iterate more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the existence of the strings. Check if the current path is a one which no other path fits (indexOf) inside of it.

```
paths.filter(function (path) {
  var keep = true;
  paths.forEach(function (another) {
      if (path.indexOf(another) === 0 && another !== path) keep = false;
  });
  return keep;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just came up with a slightly different solution too, which I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I just camp up with:

```
paths.filter(function (path) {
  return paths.every(function (another) {
     return another === path || path.indexOf(another) !== 0;
  });
});
```